# Can be logic around `List<T>.Enumerator._version` considered control flow exploitation?

Tags: c#, .net, list, .net-core

`List<T>.Enumerator` “snapshots” list version upon creation by `_version = list._version;`. This allows *enumerator* to halt enumeration when `List<T>` changed during it.

This behavior likely originates from need to move what is hidden under `foreach` statement into **forefront** while in obedience to contract (**for each**).

```cs
foreach(var i in numbers)
{
  if (i > 3)
    numbers.Remove(i);
}
```

After removal item order is shifted to left. If there is no versioning, then enumeration can continue on the 2nd next item. By this chance versioning seems fine.

In contrast

```cs
var enumerator = numbers.GetEnumerator();
while (enumerator.MoveNext())
{
  var i = enumerator.Current;
  if (i > 3)
    numbers.Remove(i);
}
```

does not have **for each** contract. Now it is just decision of `List<T>.Enumerator` to be exhaustive making sure it is.

Let consult `Sort` method

```cs
public void Sort() => Sort(0, Count, null);
public void Sort(int index, int count, IComparer<T>? comparer)
{
   … // Some code omitted. Code bellow differently formatted.   

  if (count > 1)
    Array.Sort<T>(_items, index, count, comparer);

  _version++;
}
```

I think, I wonder who would ever do

```cs
foreach(var i in numbers)
{
  if (some condition)
    numbers.Sort();
}
```

Similar applies to `Reverse`.

```cs
public void Reverse() => Reverse(0, Count);
public void Reverse(int index, int count)
{
    … // Some code omitted. Code bellow differently formatted.

  if (count > 1)  
    Array.Reverse(_items, index, count);
            
  _version++;
}
```

On other hand

```cs
foreach(var i in numbers)
{
  if (i % 3)
    numbers.Reverse();
}
```

I expect could produce nice series but I am not mathematician.

This count there are some points from which `List<T>.Enumerator` can be viewed:

1. It is exhaustive as feature and negative impact on `List<T>` and *enumerator* performance should be consumed as levy.
2. It is exhaustive as safeguard. Versioning in this case substitutes analyzer function that helps developers to avoid items miss or repeating them during enumeration due items shift. For this point penalties are debatable.
3. `List<T>` exhibits wastrel implementation.

- Versioning addresses truly only cases that causes left/right items shift copy – *removal*, *insertion*.
- Version is also handled for `Reverse`, `Sort` but what scenario allows for accidental such change during enumeration? I guess none.
- Version is handled in methods:
  `T this [int index] set` – there it can make sense but I doubt anyone would ever expect previous value when it is deliberately replaced at exact index; `Add` – adds to end and *enumerator* perfectly can work with this (relying on size), no need for version; `Clear` – affects enumeration but in safe way, check against size is sufficient; `EnsureCapacity` – I do not get how this can threat enumeration; `Insert` – avoids items repetition; `InsertRange` – avoids items miss and repetition, `RemoveAll`, `RemoveAt`, `RemoveRange` – avoids items miss
- If so then, in total, this most likely means that some methods could be freed from versioning by virtue of common sense and/or low probability of misuse while for *shifting* ones this counts still debatable.

Worth noting that `_version` is not protected against overflow. That it turn draws back to point 2. If versioning should serve run-time, should it be overflow protected? Likely.

It seems so `List<T>` versioning was designed in order to serve development (time) and there could be provided analyzers, checking shifting methods inside loops. Exception cannot go unnoticed, that is for sure. Also shift can occur outside the loop (method call).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your code. are you changing the list so many times that version overflows and goes to -1?

Comment: I cant find anything about this check making enumeration slow. do you have links?

Comment: @Ewan There’s plenty of resources about `SZArrayEnumerator` vs `List<T>.Enumerator` performance. One plain enough https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454916/performance-of-arrays-vs-lists#answer-454923.

And yes, `_version` in sample come back to its initial value, `0`.

Comment: that link doesnt mention version and neither does the jon skeet link in the comment.

Comment: @Ewan, if you compare `SZGenericArrayEnumerator<T>` with `List<T>.Enumerator` you get that they differ only in versioning logic. There’s difference also in `Current` but these could go same.

Comment: If I'm enumerating a `List<T>` and its elements move while I'm enumerating it, I want to know! If you just let it change silently it can actually introduce very hard to detect bugs. So it's a benefit, not a problem to overcome. If I want to skip the version check for some reason (e.g. for performance reasons, as you suggest, or if I want to be bale to modify it as I go), I can always access it by index, or use an array.

Comment: Hmmm… I know solutions. Was just wondering why the reason is done such way.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As I see the case, there was no best one options for authors than to exploit control flow constructs in `List<T>` methods in order to preserve common contract of **foreaching**.

I mean mostly that not everyone needs help in ensuring something is valid/complete and that nobody ever said that enumeration has to be definitely exhaustive.

When this versioning caught sight of world should be that time accompanied with at least *fast enumerator* that **does not check** against version that could be consumed manually.

Or even better whole `List<T>` should have been provided with **fast counterpart** that does not version. (*System.Collection.Performance*)

It would be copy-paste-edit epsilon-zero-like implementation.

Answer (score 6):

> So if there is change to List, there is in fact no threat to enumeration.

Yes there is. You might repeat an element, or skip it. Just because the index refers to *an element* doesn't mean the enumerator is valid.

What you've shown is that if you carefully craft a situation, you can trick one of the safety checks. You are *staggeringly* unlikely to come across this situation *accidentally*. It remains a beneficial check for the vast majority of uses.

`List` is not written to be immune to carefully crafted malice, but to be robust to ordinary situations.

Comment: I agree on rearranging before enumeration ends can produce awkward sequences. Nevertheless, `SZGenericArrayEnumerator<T>` (.NET Core) nor `SZArrayEnumerator` (.NET Framewokr) do any checks. So enumerate half array, then `Array.Reverse`, then rest is considered valid result? I would say rather than robustness hack mayhap redundancy. Why `List<T>.Reverse` means new `_version` while `Array.Reverse` not? There is little sense in `List<T>` versioning. I cannot imagine any scenario where this happens from time-to-time while in most cases there is no change before enumerator reaches end.

Comment: @Yarl regarding list vs array, I think of arrays as basically primitives, and as such they don't follow the usual rules of API design: regardless of performance considerations, they are not designed to provide any fun guarantees: they may be handed off to unmanaged code etc. so they cannot be versioned. Lists and other data-structures built with arrays, however, make certain guarantees, but may require you to use them synchronously. (that is to say, the array enumerator can't know and doesn't care what you do, which is fine by the contract of `IEnumerator`)

Comment: @VisualMelon, yes I guess you’re not wrong. I was wondering if this enumerator is some typified enumerator, e.g. state consistent enumerator. Nonetheless technically there is no need to end enumeration just because collection changed, so what would be wrong if this is analyzer rule?

Comment: @Yarl it could certainly be a useful analyser, but it wouldn't suffice to cover more dynamic cases: if the list isn't entirely local, then any virtual call could lead to its modification which would be impossible to detect by analyser without an ownership system like Rust has (i.e. if you don't know all the code that could modify the list, there is nothing you can do, and because C# lets you copy references freely this cannot be implemented in C# without an awful lot of annotations and analysers on top).

Comment: (note also that in some cases the JIT will effectively disable the version checks if it detects that it is impossible for the list to be modified on the same thread: the check is there, but it doesn't update the value of the version, so it reduces to a branch-prediction-friendly test (because it never fails), but there is more to the overhead of enumerating a list than the version checks)

Comment: @VisualMelon, great hint. I thought that analyzer solution is not cheap thus not chosen. JIT optimization is fine solution. That is for sure. So versioning outcomes as necessary evil and it looks like that and behaves same. It was chosen because better option wasn’t there. It is surprising that it was not invented any other solution. I would say `DEBUG` compilation will serve fine for this so performance is kept on par with array. It is cheaper that JIT opt. with neglectable chance to fail. Still, I see now hand that droves design decision.

Answer (score 0):

OK so, my understanding of your code is that you alter the list 2 times max int number of times. Each change increments the int _version so that it loops over max int and goes to negative max int, then all the way back up to -1.

This breaks the internal check that _version should be equal to the expected _version when you change it one more time as its now equal when you have changed the list.

Congrats you found a bug!

But. Consider how you might eliminate this bug. If you just change it to long then you still have the same bug, just a higher number of changes. Its not a trivial problem to solve as you essentially have n possible versions of a list, with no real limit.

Should you prevent changes to a list which has reached your max?
Should you invalidate linked enumerations when the underlying list changes?

We can only guess on the reasons why this way was chosen, you can see that all options have downsides. However! Given that _version is int and not uint, I have feeling this is just an oversight and it should be possible to implement a fix without major downsides.

Comment: `Given that _version is int and not uint, I have feeling this is just an oversight` I don't follow: why would `uint` be significant?

Comment: _version is only ever incremented and starts at 0. Although it makes no difference to a comparison, a human thinking about it would naturally choose a uint and then consider overflow and then ulong. If it was ulong or uint, or even byte I would assume a conscious choice where  sign and max had been taken into consideration. But int? its just the default.

Comment: `uint` isn't CLS, which may be factor (shouldn't matter though)? Anyhow, your last sentence reads as though changing to `uint` would be a fix, which I'm guessing wasn't the intention :P

Comment: no, im just trying to guess at intentions

Comment: Problem is not bug or performance in core but sense saturation. If versioning should prevent unintentional changes during `foreach` what scenario can be about to `Reverse`, `Sort`, `RemoveAll` during `foreach` enumeration? Still these make new version. When enumerating `(while(enumerator.MoveNext())` it’s really on ease that anyone does stopping it intentionally to make changes not otherwise but this is not possible. So, versioning proofs to not be any conceptual enumerator implementation, rather serves development time. Proper code never causes version violation during production run.

Comment: Also `List<T>` is not thread-safe by its nature, so versioning serves only single threaded scenario (basically same as r/w synchronized at first place). It is obvious that only senseful usage is uncovering that `foreach` does not snapshots collection it enumerates. It seems there are better solutions to this but not cheap, worthwhile ones. I would say enumerator versioning is not bullet-proof since it wasn’t mean to be at any time. Versioning there supplies analyzers function.

Comment: not sure I follow your grammar. The most usual case where enumeration is prevented is where you attempt to change the list inside the enumeration loop. Which seems like desired behaviour to me